# CSS3 Animation -> re-invoke failure

Tags: javascript, css, invoke, css-animations

Problem: Once again change the selected value, the animation of the text does not start

My Browser: Firefox 26.0

```
//Example
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HQBVP/1/

Comment: Explain your requirement clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, add cross browser support to your css3 animations (i just added `-webkit`)

http://jsfiddle.net/HQBVP/2/

I think this should solve your problem.